# C# Array Contents not showing, but type is

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, messagebox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] myArray = { "Eddie", "Amber", "Kelly" };

    public void showMe()
    {
        foreach (string i in myArray) 
            MessageBox.Show(myArray.ToString()); 

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => showMe();
}
```

Hi everybody,

I'm trying to get the names from `myArray` to be shown in the `MessageBox`, but all I'm getting is a `MessageBox` with `System.String[]` and I'm not sure why?
 Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behaviour of `ToString()`. It just prints the type name of the object, unless defined otherwise for a specific type.

You want to use

```
foreach (string i in myArray)
    MessageBox.Show(i);
```

to display a separate messagebox for each element in the array or

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", myArray));
```

to display a single messagebox with all elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you were iterating each element in the array, and displaying the type of the array `myArray.ToString()` which was the problem

The solve

```
foreach (string item in myArray)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

or Just (to show them all at once)

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",",myArray));
```

---

[String.Join Method (String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified
>   separator between each element.

[Object.ToString Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx#Default)

Comment: Thanks very much :)